# How do I identify the voice I hear when loading IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, voice

I don't really use IE for general browsing, but I'm trying to test my site on it. However, when I now run it, some random voice comes up explaining how I to clear my cache and cookies. Where is this voice coming from?! My homepage is the default MSN one. I don't know when this started happening, but it might have been since the MS updates on Tuesday. Has anyone else heard of this, or have I got some weird malware?

---

**Edit:**

It seems to only appear when javascript is turned off and I restart IE.

**Edit 2:**

When disconnected from the internet, the voice doesn't start.
To reproduce: Goto Tools...Internet options....Security...Custom Level... and under 'Active Scripting', disable it. Then restart IE and wait a moment (don't change/refresh page).

Comment: Make sure to run your anti-virus and anti-malware software.  It sounds like you got something you didn't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen nor heard of this happening in IE.  Definitely sounds like malware, or perhaps part of an IE plugin or toolbar (most toolbar plugins are at the least adware and many are spyware/malware).  I suppose, though, that it could be something MSN has added to their homepage if it detects that JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: It seems to happen with any homepage, as long as javascript is off. I tried running IE without extensions (iexplore -extoff) and that stopped the voice. However, I don't have any extensions installed when I go to the manager.

Answer (score 1):

My gut says it's a virus. However...

MS Windows includes some aids to help people who are "handicapped." There may be a voice synthasizer that's audiblizing some message Windows wants to give you. You can find out by going to Programs -> Accessories -> Accessability. From there you will find a few utilities.

RT

Comment: I tried running a scan with OneCare and didn't pick up anything. It seems to happen on any homepage, as long as I boot up IE. I haven't cleared the cache/cookies following its instructions, just incase it's a virus which is executed by doing that.